# "Implict declaration" of a function from c standard library? (the header file has already been included)

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

the function gcvt is included in stdlib.h.
When I try to compile this:

```
    gcc -std=c99 problem.c 2.c -o problem
```

I got the imformation:

```
     warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gcvt’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 fstr = gcvt(datad,10,buff);
```

And It can't be executed correctly.

But I can fix this by adding one line in 2.c before function test:

```
   char *gcvt(double number, int ndigit, char *buf);
```

Does anyone know why ?

Here is my code:

2.c

```
    #include "2.h"
    //char *gcvt(double number, int ndigit, char *buf);--must add this line
    void test() {

        double datad = 2.3;

        char buff[100];
        char *fstr; 
        fstr = gcvt(datad,10,buff); 


        printf("%s",fstr);
   }
```

2.h

```
    #ifndef XXX 
    #define XXX 
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    void test();
    #endif
```

problem.c

```
    #include "2.h"

    int main()
    {
        test();    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's a function that was marked as obsolete 15 years ago that should not be used. The system probably just doesn't include declarations for stuff that they don't want you to use. Just use `snprintf`.

Comment: @Art You're exactly right.  You should make that an answer.

Comment: This is not a standard C function, thus not required to be in the standard libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for gcc says:

```
  gcvt(): _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
```

This means that the definition is dependent on a macro.

Add this **before** any `#include` directives:

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
```

The man page also recommends that you use `snprintf` instead, because `gcvt`is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

The function you want to call has been marked as obsolete 15 years ago. The normal way to discourage people from using those functions (without actually breaking programs) is to have the implementation of the function left in the standard library, but remove the declaration from header files (or at least make it hard to enable).

Use `snprintf` instead to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: This is good advice but doesn't answer why the issue is happening, which is almost surely a missing feature test macro.

Comment: @R.. The issue is happening because of use of an obsolete function. Everything else is symptoms or workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

On most systems, the `-std=c99` option (actually the `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro that gcc predefines as a result) causes the system headers to adhere to the C standard for what identifiers they can expose in the namespace. Since `gcvt` is not a standard function, it cannot be exposed. If you want to request it, you'll probably need to define a *Feature Test Macro* like `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` (Issue 6 was the last version of the Single Unix Specification to support this long-obsolete function) before including any of the standard headers; the easiest way to do this is on the command line:

```
gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 ...
```

But really you should follow the advice of the other answers and use `snprintf`, not this long-obsolete junk function.

Comment: Since glibc 2.12, `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` will, in fact, suppress the prototype for `gcvt()`.  You need `_XOPEN_SOURCE` defined with a value in the half-open range [500, 600), or one of a few other variations, for such versions of glibc.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Are you sure. If so, and they claim to be supporting Issue 6, that's a bug. Only in Issue 7 (value of 700) was it removed.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `gcvt()` is in the standard library is a matter of interpretation.  It is not among the standard library functions defined by C.  It was documented as a legacy function in POSIX.1-2001, but it has been altogether removed in POSIX.1-2008, so these days there is nothing standard about it.

As a practical matter, however, it *is* in Glibc, and `stdlib.h` is the correct header for its prototype, so you might say it's in the standard library in that sense.  Personally, I consider that misleading and / or misunderstood.

It is generally a good idea to consult the documentation of functions that you are not completely familiar with.  In this case, you will find in the [Glibc docs for this function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gcvt) that it has a feature-test macro requirement:

> Since glibc 2.12:
>
> ```
> _SVID_SOURCE ||
>     (_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 ||
>         _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED) &&
>     !(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600)
> ```

In order for the prototype to be available, that preprocessor conditional must evaluate to true while `stdlib.h` is being processed.  You might provide for that by ensuring that the symbol `_XOPEN_SOURCE` is defined with value `500`, and that `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is either undefined, or defined with a value less than `200112L`.  For example, pass `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` to `gcc`.